# Mobile site works great on iPhone and Android, not at all on Blackberry

Tags: javascript, blackberry, mobile

I have a site that basically is a landing page for a QR code gives two options, one for each different video. The resize and orientation feature works great and all, but once this site is on blackberry nothing works. Javascript is working but it's not resizing my div's, everything is huge and zoomed in, nothing is floated right, what the hell is up? any ideas? here's the site...

http://dudnyk.com/files/oleptro_redirect/index.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some HTML elements are not supported for all the Blackberry Browsers...

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6176/HTML_ref_div_561799_11.jsp

in fact HTML5 is supported for Iphone and Android that are based on Webkit, disgracefully only in Blackberry OS 6.0 =(

Update:
[HTML5 Elements for BlackBerry](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/08/blackberry-html5/)